# Visiting Daintree Rainforest on an budget

Tags: budget, australia, daintree

In the Lonely Planet guide for Australia Daintree is the top #6 attraction. The guide book claims there are (among other things) mountain treks, self-guided walking trails, kayaking, croc-spotting cruises. However, the guide doesn't really offer a decent explanation what exactly is worth seeing there. They point to page 449, which only give some historic background of how the park was established. The chapter seems to be a listing of tour companies, restaurants and hotels arranged geographically, which just doesn't help to choose anything.

Could someone list the most worthy things (that are specific for this area/different from the rest) and how to visit them on a budget?

Comment: Could you please edit to be more specific? "on a budget" - could be $100, or $10,000.  Are you backpacking? Do you want a tour, or do you want to self-guide?  The more specific, the more likely you'll be to get a useful answer :)  I'm also interested as eyeing up that area for November this year...

Comment: @MarkMayo, that's the thing - I want to pay as little as possible to see all the relevant things there. Absolute maximum would be $300 (because I have been offered a tour for $350)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Daintree is a prehistoric rainforest that could be considered a natural wonder of the world.  However...

It has not been set up to be very tourist-friendly.  To get through the rainforest itself, you pretty much need to be on a tour or staying at one of the lodges because the national park itself has not been developed like many others of Australia's - http://www.daintree.info/walks2.html lists some walks, but to get the most out of them a knowledgeable guide does not go astray.

Overall seeing the Daintree on a budget would involve staying at a cheaper hotel/hostel in Cairns or Port Douglas and renting a car for a day trip, as this should work out cheaper than a tour if you have more than one person going.  Sights to see would include the Daintree Discovery Centre, Daintree Ice Cream Company, a croc spotting boat ride in the river, the beaches, and some of the walks above.

Answer (score 3):

[Crocodylus Village](http://daintreecrocodylus.com.au/crocodylusvillage/Home.html) is a decent hostel near the Daintree Rainforest and Daintree River.

Has laundry facilities.

Price range on 4/5/2012: A$25-95